# How to hide Visual Studio attach to process popup window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have attached VS2015 to process and after I finished my debugging I closed out and reopened my solution. Now whenever I'm debugging my own application I see pop-up menu that I'm not sure how to hide.

[image]

Any ideas what this pop-up menu is called and where is the setting to hide/show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try unchecking this option: Tools –> Options –> Debugging –> General –> Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML.

Comment: That worked thanks... It would have taken me forever to find it.

Comment: You can refer this link http://xamlnative.com/2016/04/08/visual-studio-2015-update-2-xaml-debugging-improvements/ for more details.